# Antlr3 warning: Decison can match multiple alternatives but I don't see how

Tags: antlr, antlr3, lexer

Here is the warning message in question:

> BB_LLVM2AST.g:120:15: Decision can match input such as "'a'..'z'" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2
>   As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input

And here is the rule:

```
fragment
IDENTIFIER
:
 ((LOWERCHARS)+ (('0'..'9')+)? PERIOD?)+ 
|   ('0'..'9')+ 
;
```

here are the other rules called:

```
fragment
LOWERCHARS
:
('a'..'z')
;

fragment
PERIOD
:
'.'
;
```

So, I tried using syntactic predicates, but still have the same warning message.

```
fragment
IDENTIFIER
:
 (LOWERCHARS) => ((LOWERCHARS)+ (INT)? PERIOD?)+ 
|(INT)  => INT  
;
```

I took out an INT fragment that was there in a blind attempt to get rid of the warning. I don't understand how `input such as "'a'..'z'` could possibly be matched using an alternative where the alternative is `('0'..'9')`. Also, what can I do to get rid of this warning? I hate warning messages.

Comment: ANTLR 4's lexer implementation is *so much* better than ANTLR 3's implementation, you should really switch if at all possible. There is a reason there are no Stack Overflow questions like this for ANTLR 4 lexer users (and it's not due to it being newer).

Comment: I wish I could, but I'm doing coursework and the professor has chosen ANTLR 3 for some reason.